# How Could I increase the speed

Tags: python, image-processing

I am using below code for an image processing related study. The code works fine as functionality but it is too slow that one step takes up to 10 seconds.

I need faster process speed to reach at the aim.

```
import numpy
import glob, os
import cv2
import os
    input = cv2.imread(path)

    def nothing(x):  # for trackbar
        pass


    windowName = "Image"

    cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
    cv2.createTrackbar("coef", windowName, 0, 25000, nothing)

    condition = True
    while (condition):
        coef = cv2.getTrackbarPos("coef", windowName)
        temp_img = input
        row = temp_img.shape[0]
        col = temp_img.shape[1]
        print(coef)
        red = []
        green = []
        for i in range(row):
            for y in range(col):
               # temp_img[i][y][0] = 0
                temp_img[i][y][1] = temp_img[i][y][1]* (coef / 100)
                temp_img[i][y][1] = temp_img[i][y][2] * (1 - (coef / 100))
                # relative_diff = value_g - value_r

        # temp =cv2.resize(temp,(1000,800))
        cv2.imshow(windowName, temp_img)
        # cv2.imwrite("output2.jpg", temp)
        print("fin")
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) >= 0:
            condition = False
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there anybody have an idea having faster result on the aim?

Comment: @depperm With the current lack of context, it's not acceptable there. We don't know anything about the input at this time, what the code is supposed to do or the code surrounding this function.

Comment: @Mast but it is also not acceptable here as there is no problem except improvement

Comment: I have written in different way but it was converted automatically.

Comment: Please read [mre]. Answers cannot be correct if we cannot run your code to compare.

Comment: the code is updated now you can reach the whole code and run it just with pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what object temp_img is exactly, but if it behaves like a numpy array, you could replace your loop by

```
temp_img[:,:,0] = temp_img[:,:,1]*(coef/100)
temp_img[:,:,1] = temp_img[:,:,2]*(1-coef/1000)
```

which should result in a significant speed up if your array is large. The implementation of such operations on arrays are optimised very well, whereas python loops are generally quite slow.

Edit based on comments:
Since you're working with large images and have some expensive operations that need an unscaled version but only need to be executed once, your code could get the following kind of structure

```
import... #do all your imports

def expensive_operations(image, *args, **kwargs):
    #do all your expensive operations like object detection

def scale_image(image, scale):
    #create a scaled version of image

def cheap_operations(scaled_image, windowName):
    #perform cheap operations, e.g.
    coef = cv2.getTrackbarPos("coef", windowName)
    temp_img = np.copy(scaled_image)
    temp_img[:,:,1] = temp_img[:,:,1]* (coef / 100)
    temp_img[:,:,2] = temp_img[:,:,2] * (1 - (coef / 100))
    cv2.imshow(windowName, temp_img)



input = cv2.imread(path)
windowName = "Image"

cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
cv2.createTrackbar("coef", windowName, 0, 25000, nothing)

condition = True

expensive_results = expensive_operations(input) #possibly with some more args and keyword args
scaled_image = scale_image(input)

while condition:
    cheap_operations(scaled_image, windowName)
    if cv2.waitKey(30) >= 0:
        condition = False

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This is right I have already tried this one but it crashes. Temp_img is the instant image for each steps on converting.

Comment: What exactly is the type of temp_img? And what module are you using? Maybe you could convert temp_img to a numpy array?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Could you provide information on your meant with the one line code? Just one layer is enough.

Comment: Okay, when I tried this, cv2.imread gave me a numpy array, so the code should work. The first line means that for all indices i and j, temp_img[i,j,0] should be appointed the value temp_img[i,j,1]*(coef/100). 

It looks like you've changed your code though, so it should now be:

```
temp_img[:,:,1] = temp_img[:,:,1]* (coef / 100)
temp_img[:,:,1] = temp_img[:,:,2] * (1 - (coef / 100))
```
although it looks to me like you've made some mistake since you're setting the same elements twice with different values now.

Comment: To understand the syntax better, this might be a useful resource: https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/BasicIndexing.html

Comment: thank you. So, as you said I have been already using your approach but the result is too slow.

Comment: Could you post your new code? And have you tried timing the various parts of your code to see what the bottleneck is now?

Comment: I haven't used the updated code. The one I have is the same with the above. This is the fastest one I had. Unfortunately, there is no other way to increase the speed :(

Comment: I strongly doubt that. Testing locally, using slices and numpy views is orders of magnitude faster than using a double for loop even when the arrays are small like 10x10x3 in shape.

Comment: My handicap here is that my images are standard and around min 20 MP. This is strongly the issue :(

Comment: So all the more reason why I can't possibly believe that a double for loop is the fastest approach. But in that case both approaches will be too slow. What you could do is use a lower resolution image for displaying everything, and only manipulating the full image upon saving. So let temp_img be a lower resolution copy of your input image, work with that to let the user see the affect of various values of coef, and then when the user decides to save the image (what seems to be the point of your code, perform your manipulations on the full image and save that.

Comment: I can not lower the resolution because my objects are very small and they are adjacent each other so in lower resolution I can not make them detect. I will try to live_view processing to increase the performance.

Comment: But you only need to do object detection once per image right? So do all the things that you need to do only once per image on the large original, and then perform all the actions you really do need to do continuously on the down scaled image. Moreover try to not use any for loops but use slices and views in numpy instead to make every operation perform as fast as possible.

Comment: Yes that's right. Your recommendation attracted me but I need to know what exactly you mean. Could you provide example on your advice?

Comment: It is still the same not hing is changed. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of thing in [nip2](https://github.com/libvips/nip2). It's an image processing spreadsheet that can manipulate huge images quickly. It has no problems doing this kind of operation on any size image at 60fps.

I made you an example workspace: http://www.rollthepotato.net/~john/coeff.ws

Here's what it looks like working on a 1gb starfield image:

[image]

You can drag the slider to change `coeff`. The processed image updates instantly as you drag. You can zoom and pan around the processed image to check details and adjust `coeff`.

The underlying image processing library is [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/), which has a Python binding, [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/). In pyvips, your program would be:

```
import pyvips

def adjust(image, coeff):
    return image * [1, coeff / 100, 1 - coeff / 100]
```

Though that's without the GUI elements, of course.